# php code for print description in each post?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

i have code for title tag `<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>`

I need a description tag code like this to print anywhere on the page

I'm created custom template so only this problem please anyone tell the answer

Comment: Can you share me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

```
$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
echo $content;
```